# Stop webViewDidFinishLoad from being called rapidly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sdk

In my `webViewDidFinishLoad` method, I have the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {   
    if (hasPressed == 1) {
        hasPressed = 0;
        isBlocked = 0;
    }
    else if (hasPressed == 0 && hasDroppedDown == 0) {
        if (viewState != kStateWeather || isBlocked == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                              delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
                                  //Animations
                              }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             hasDroppedDown = 1;
                         }];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if this method is called rapidly, e.g. a website that has a redirect, the `else` in my `else if` becomes useless. How do I stop it from being called so rapidly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant do that. It will call when ever a new URL is start loading in the `UIWebView`. Instead you can do one thing.
Implement the delegate function

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This delegate will be called when a new frame is about to start loading in the `UIWebView`.
You can figure out which type of request is going to load by checking the `navigationType` which can attain values

```
UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked
UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted
UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward
UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload
UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted
UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther
```

**Note**: return `YES` if you allow the webview to load the page else `NO`.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)main { //being called every 0.2
    t+=0.2;
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {   
    loadImg.hidden = 1;
    m_activity.hidden= TRUE;     
    [m_activity stopAnimating];
    if (t>0.5) {
        [self finishedLoading];
        t=0;
    }
}
- (void)finishedLoading {
    if (hasPressed == 1) {
        hasPressed = 0;
        isBlocked = 0;
    }
    else if (hasPressed == 0 && hasDroppedDown == 0) {
        if (viewState != kStateWeather || isBlocked == 0) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                                  delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
                                      //Animations
                                  }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 hasDroppedDown = 1;
                             }];
        }
    }
}
```